# Mohr's Circle explanation in detail in simple languagr

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

Someone please explain me Mohr's circle in detail in a simple language

Comment: related https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/12884/7461

Answer (score 2):

Mohr's circle is a graphical representation of the state of stress at a point. Once the Mohr's circle for a point is constructed, we can easily determine the normal and shear stress components on any plane passing through that point. 
While using the Mohr's circle the vertical axis represents shear stress and the horizontal axis represents normal stress. If we draw a radius at the same angle of inclination with horizontal axis as that of the plane whose stress components are to be determined, then the vertical projection of the radius gives the shear stress and the horizontal projection gives the normal stress in the scale you have chosen.

For constructing the Mohr's circle for a point, given the stress components are  N`x` and N`y` being normal stress components and T being the shear stress component in a particular plane inclined at angle Z. First establish a coordinate system with vertical and horizontal axes. Then locate the point on the horizontal axis such that its coordinate is the average of N`x` and N`y`. Then draw a circle with radius equal to vector sum of 0.5(N`x`- N`y`) and T. ie the square root of the sum of the squares of these. This completes the Mohr's circle.